# DB oracle Closed Connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

## Introdução

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e tenho que adicionar dados a um banco de dados oracle que está local. Utilizando o JDBC faço a conexão

```
 try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + conexao + ":1521:xe", "system", "root")){
            System.out.println("Conectado a "+conexao);
            return (Connection) conn;
        }
```

Conexão é feita com sucesso.
Agora preciso fazer a inserção. Tenho o seguinte código:

#### PessoaDAO.java

```
public void insert(String conexao) throws SQLException{
        // Instancia classe de conexão 
        Connection conn = ConnDb.getConnection(conexao);
        String query = "insert into TESTE2 (TITLE) values('asd')";
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
           stmt.execute();
           conn.commit();
        }catch(SQLException e){
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }            
    }
```

E oque é disparado quando clicado em um botão

```
String conexao= localConexao.getText();
         try {
            p = new PessoaDAO();
            p.insert(conexao);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
```

#### Erro

Ele cai em um `SQLException` não fazendo a inserção.

> Closed Connection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está fechando a conexão logo depois de abri-la:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + conexao + ":1521:xe", "system", "root")){
            System.out.println("Conectado a "+conexao);
            return (Connection) conn;

// a linha abaixo libera os recursos alocados quando da criação de "conn"; ou seja, fecha a conexão com o banco.
        }
```

Para testar o restante do seu código, remova o `try` da criação da conexão:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + conexao + ":1521:xe", "system", "root");
System.out.println("Conectado a "+conexao);
return (Connection) conn;
```

É claro que agora sua conexão permanecerá aberta e eventualmente você precisará criar outra maneira de gerenciá-la.

Veja: [Java Tutorials - The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: @Caffé era isso mesmo! obrigado =)